# Powers producing NaN in R

Tags: r, indices

R seems to be doing something weird when I am calculating powers. For example if i run the following code

```
xt <- -0.96 
betat <- 0.39
xt^betat
```

then the answer produced is given as NaN. However if it put -0.96^0.39 in to the console, it produced an answer (-0.9842055). The only difference in the first section i have assigned a variable. Is there any way of giving the actual answer rather than the NaN?

The issue lies with negative xt values.

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

The console is evaluating:

```
-(0.96^0.39)
```

because of order of operations. If you specify parenthesis you get `NaN` as expected:

```
(-0.96)^0.39
# [1] NaN
```